# BJTs max VCE voltage

Tags: transistors, bjt

If I ground the base of a NPN transistor (which means no current is passing through the transistor) with a VCE limit of 60 V, can I connect a higher voltage than its rating to collector of the transistor?

Comment: No you can't. Read the data sheet or link a data sheet.

Comment: What is your understanding of Vce limit? What do you think might happen when you exceed it? [Edit] your thoughts into the question.

Comment: *If I ground the base of a NPN transistor (which means no current is passing through the transistor)* You mean **short the base and emitter**. Grounding the base isn't enough unless you ground the emitter as well. Also, ground is **just a reference point**. When I connect both base and emitter to + 5 V, with the collector at + 10 V, still (almost) no current flows.

Comment: The maximum Vce (valid for Vcb as well) **doesn't care** is current is flowing or not. If you want more that Vce = 60 V you will need to use a **different transistor**.

Comment: **can I connect a higher voltage than its rating to collector of the transistor?** Absolutely. Yes you can. The transistor will likely be destroyed, but that's not the question you asked. To avoid destroying the transistor, keep VCE below 60 V.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a typical commonly used BJT data sheet: -

[image]

> *If I ground the base of a NPN transistor (which means no current is
> passing through the transistor) with a VCE limit of 60 V, can I
> connect a higher voltage than its rating to collector of the
> transistor?*

If you ground the base (i.e. connect it to 0 volts) then the collector voltage maximum (repeat maximum) voltage is 60 volts (irrespective of current being passed or not). That's what a maximum rating is - it's the point-of-abuse limit. Anything above is abuse and anything closer to 0 volts is not abuse. In truth though, to obtain best reliability you shouldn't really get to within 75% of that maximum limit. And by that I mean around 45 volts. And, I don't mean an average voltage I mean an instantaneous value so, 60 volts for 1 femtosecond or half an hour is equally abusive.

Comment: Thanks, I'm building a electronic load which I defined the maximum input voltage to 50V, I want to protect the BJT from over voltage, the input voltage is being monitored and read by an MCU. I was thinking to use a relay at the input but I couldn't find any relay with DC voltage rating of higher than 30V. do you think using a varistor is my only option?

Comment: I can't visualize how a varistor or relay will help protect your transistor. Why not get a transistor that is 100 volt rated?

Comment: You mean they're too slow? I can't find the right transistor with TO-3 package, my only option is 2N3055 OR risk the money and buy something from a salvage store...

Comment: No, I can't visualize your circuit.

Comment: I'll send the schematic to you once finished. basically it's just two power transistors in parallel driven by a high gain transistor in darlington configuration, op amp measures the voltage drop over a shunt sets the output current. I was thinking to monitor the input voltage and only connect the input to the collector when voltage is in the safe area but now that I'm thinking, what if voltage changes and gets over the limit after the relay is connected? so I thought maybe a varistor could help...

Comment: Add it to the post because it should be open to others please. Or raise a new question because I'm too busy at the moment to do private stuff. Sorry.

Comment: I'll probably supply an answer if you post here but others might beat me to it LOL

Comment: Edited the question, appreciate the help.

Comment: No, you shouldn't edit this question because it's already completed. Raise a new question targeted at protecting the transistors.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry...